# Give the whole workspace as input of a function?

Tags: r, function

I would like to build up a function that, as input, accepts all the workspace... How can I achieve this?

Comment: This defeats the purpose of having a function in the first place. I would reconsider this course of action. There must be a way to structure your code that does not involve passing the entire workspace.

Comment: Agree with @PaulHiemstra ...  no need to pass the whole workspace. Think through your function arguments. Passing an entire workspace opens the door to error.

Comment: `eapply` can be use to loop through an environment. `eapply(.GlobalEnv,c)` will give you a list containing everything in the global environment, as will `as.list(.GlobalEnv)`.